# PYTHON: How do i split the middle of a string from an unknown amount of characters in the input?

Tags: python

I have a project to replace the last 3 numbers with the original first 3 numbers and the first 3 numbers with the original last 3 numbers of an input if the starting number of the input is 0 and the last 3 numbers add up to 9. I did it by using this:

```
  end = num[-3:]
  start = num[:3]
  end_sum = int(end[0]) + int(end[1]) + int(end[2])
  if int(num[0]) == 0:
    if end_sum == 9:
```

Now the problem is I don't know how to print this. I tried using .replace() but it only replaces one element, it does not switch both the elements around. And the amount of characters in the input is unknown, so I can't just do like [3:7] or something like that. I'm really confused, I'd really like help thanks! :D

Comment: You can still use a negative index relative to the end. I would build a new list as the output.

Answer (score 1):

```
end = num[-3:]
start = num[:3]
middle = num[3:-3]
print(end + middle + start)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
l = [0, 3, 4, 5, 2, 3, 4, 3, 4, 2]

if l[0] == 0 and sum(l[-3:]) == 9:
     first = l[:3]
     last = l[-3:]
     final_list = last+l[3:7]+first
```